# Is there a limit to number of CSOM requests in SharePoint online for Throttling

Tags: sharepoint-online

I read the documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online) and it explains about Throttling

But it does not specify the exact number of requests that can be made with one account over a period of time, say one hour.

Comment: "Why can't you just tell me the exact throttling limits" -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#why-cant-you-just-tell-me-the-exact-throttling-limits

Answer (score 0):

Hi Vignesh Subramanian,

Regardless of what entry-point in SharePoint we use (Graph, CSOM, etc.) those calls are turned into SQL queries or calls to lower-level infrastructure which quickly ramp up the CPU usage on that server. These calls are unpredictable and hard to plan for on the database side. As a result, MS does not expose exact rate limit.

Instead, it responses a Retry-After HTTP header to let your code back off "just enough" if it hits throttling limits.

It's suggested you [handle SharePoint Online throttling by using exponential back off](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/handle-sharepoint-online-throttling-by-using-exponential-back-off). You may also have a look SharePoint Patterns and Practices:

- https://github.com/pnp/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.Throttling
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#csom-code-sample-executequerywithincrementalretry-extension-method

BR